# How to access inner alias in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, join, union, alias

I need this condition for my stored procedure, can I in any way access alias declared in inner level from outside its context

This works:-

```
SELECT Count(*)
FROM   (SELECT id
        FROM   postdata
        WHERE  id IN ( 4, 5, 6 )
        UNION
        SELECT id
        FROM   (SELECT id,
                       date_completed
                FROM   postdata
                WHERE  id IN ( 1, 2, 3 ))a
        WHERE  a.date_completed in  ( "2012-1-10", "2012-10-02" ) )b
```

is there a possibility to make this work

```
SELECT Count(*)
FROM   (SELECT id
        FROM   postdata
        WHERE  id IN ( 4, 5, 6 )
        UNION
        SELECT id
        FROM   (SELECT id,
                       date_completed
                FROM   postdata
                WHERE  id IN ( 1, 2, 3 ))a)b
WHERE  a.date_completed IN ( "2012-1-10", "2012-10-02" )
```

Comment: Can you be a little more specific about what you're trying to achieve ? Besides an alias mistake, the second query is syntaxically correct, althoug different from the first one.

Comment: The above query is just an example representation it has nothing to do with the real implementation 
what I really want is a way to achieve access to inner alias which is 'a' in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, there's no way to access the inner alias `a`.

You'll have to add a discriminant in your inner queries:

```
SELECT Count(*)
FROM   (SELECT 'a' AS discriminant,
               id
        FROM   postdata
        WHERE  id IN ( 4, 5, 6 )
        UNION
        SELECT 'b' AS discriminant,
               id
        FROM   (SELECT id,
                       date_completed
                FROM   postdata
                WHERE  id IN ( 1, 2, 3 ))a)b
WHERE  b.discriminant= 'a'
        OR ( b.discriminant= 'b'
             AND b.id IN ( 1, 2 ) )
```

See [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cb5e7/6).

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply that worked for me I guess i can mold it to work my case